# How to start designing T-Shirts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, graphic-styles

So it's possible that I could have a few clients (Minor music brands) that would like me to design some T-Shirts for them.
I don't know where to start.
I can work Illustrator and Photoshop CS6 and CC.
I'm not sure if I would need to use a template or what.
Once I have the design finished how should I send it to the client? PDF? JPG?

As of now all that I can think of is that I would probably be working in Illustrator for the most part with a CMYK workspace and I know how to use general Rules like the rule of thirds and stuff and I can run the software it's just I've never embarked on something like this.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is a pretty broad question. Can you whittle it down for us? Visit the help section in the headers above to better frame your situation and ask your question. Don't forget to search for related answers that already suit you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid sending native application format files.

A good way to send your graphics files is in a PDF/X-1A. 
Refer to [Prepressure.com](http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/pdfx-1a) to continue this segment your education

When you have a more detailed question come back for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Users have already comented you that it is too board...

Designing envolves all the process from conceptualization to the previous step to print.

> I don't know where to start.

The first question is... Can you design?

> I'm not sure if I would need to use a template or what.

Good luck not everyone works on templates... for a design, but probably you can use a vector t-shirt to propose some ideas.

https://www.google.com/search?q=vector+T+shirt

> I know how to use general Rules like the rule of thirds

That is a "general" rule of composition for photography... So I am back to the first question.

> Illustrator for the most part with a CMYK workspace

If the design is one ink? If has two direct colors? More?

> PDF?JPG?

See Stan's answer.

> I've never embarked on something like this.

See if it is ethic to do something you have never done. A t-shirt could be one of the simplests projects there is... if you know what are you doing.

> I can run the software

**!?**

Comment: When I said I could run the software that was a poor choice of words on my part, I meant that I can work it and I know how to use it.